# Why can't gio load info for my handler?

Tags: gnome, zoom-meeting, xdg

I'm trying to set up zoom and having a bit of trouble. At the top level, I would like to be able to open `zoommtg:` links with `xdg-open`. I get this right now:

```
% xdg-open zoommtg:
gio: zoommtg:: The specified location is not supported
% gio open zoommtg: # digging in xdg-open, this is where it finally bottoms out
gio: zoommtg:: The specified location is not supported
```

Looking around online, it seems I should register a desktop entry file with the `x-scheme-handler/zoommtg` MIME type. Okay, the zoom tarball ships with such a file.

```
% gio mime x-scheme-handler/zoommtg ZoomLauncher.desktop
gio: Failed to load info for handler “ZoomLauncher.desktop”
```

I have confirmed that a file with the appropriate name exists, is on my `XDG_DATA_DIRS` search path, and is a valid desktop file that claims to support that MIME type:

```
% echo $XDG_DATA_DIRS
/home/dmwit/inst/links/share:/usr/share/pop:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/
% desktop-file-validate ~/inst/links/share/applications/ZoomLauncher.desktop
/home/dmwit/inst/links/share/applications/ZoomLauncher.desktop: warning: key "Encoding" in group "Desktop Entry" is deprecated
% grep zoommtg !$
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/zoommtg;x-scheme-handler/zoomus;x-scheme-handler/tel;x-scheme-handler/callto;x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall;
X-KDE-Protocols=zoommtg;zoomus;tel;callto;zoomphonecall
```

(Deleting the deprecated entry has no effect, so I believe the problem is not related to the warning.) So why can't `gio` load it?

Comment: Try this : `xdg-mime default ZoomLauncher.desktop x-scheme-handler/zoommtg`

Comment: @harrymc I believe the default is already correct. When I run `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/zoommtg`, it prints `ZoomLauncher.desktop`.

Comment: Check `~/.local/share/applications` for a `Zoom*.desktop` file without `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/zoommtg`. If added, do `sudo update-desktop-database`. Check also system wide locations `/usr/share/applications` or `/usr/local/share/applications`.

Comment: @harrymc I don't see a `Zoom*.desktop` in any of those locations. Additionally, running `sudo updatedb && locate ZoomLauncher.desktop` shows only the one from the question (and its link target, obviously), and `locate *.desktop | grep Zoom` similarly. I re-ran `sudo update-desktop-database` (actually, I found I needed to `sudo --preserve-env=XDG_DATA_DIRS update-desktop-database` for it to update all the right locations), but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I spent a little quality time with `gdb` and simultaneously went source-diving. It turns out that the executable path specified in `ZoomLauncher.desktop` was incorrect! After pointing it at the right location, everything went completely hunky-dory.

The error message given by `gio` for this problem leaves a lot to be desired...